# Enable submit button after all fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a jquery toggling menu with password fields.
By default, the submit button is disabled, and enabled on keyup events.

```
$(function(){
  $("#submitProfile").attr("disabled","true");
  $("#password_confirmation, #password, #current_password").keyup(function(){
    $("#submitProfile").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

But how can I keep the button disabled until all the fields are filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a condition.

```
$(function(){
  $("#submitProfile").attr("disabled","true");
  $("#password_confirmation, #password, #current_password").keyup(function(){
      if($("#password_confirmation").val() && $("#password").val() && $("#current_password").val())
          $("#submitProfile").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rwoughe2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
if($('#password_confirmation, #password, #current_password').val().length>0){
 $("#submitProfile").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Did you try your code? Your solution doesn't work on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwoughe2/3/)